# Is there a correlation between people who frequently laugh at their own jokes and narcissism?

Tags: social-psychology, humour

It is not uncommon for people to  laugh at their own jokes. One comedian discusses how he uses this as a benchmark for whether or not a joke is going to be funny for the audience.

[Psychology Today interviews John Hodgman](http://boingboing.net/2009/06/22/psychology-today-int.html)

> Your delivery is famously dry. Do you ever crack yourself up? I find
>   it to be comedically unethical to laugh at your own jokes on stage.
>   ...//...
>
> But the reverse is true when writing. I generally only like a joke of
>   my own if I make myself laugh when I write it. If my brain can fool
>   myself into a surprised chuckle, even when I am the one who wrote the
>   joke, my guess is that it can also fool you.

Is there a correlation between  people who frequently laugh at their own jokes and narcissistic features?

Comment: From personal experience: I really don't see myself as a narcissist, however I can be selfish (aren't we all a little bit). I laugh at my own jokes a lot, mostly because only I get the joke. I see humor in the smallest things, things that are just silly, ironic, and oh how I love puns! It feels good to laugh! My husband just stares at me and shakes his head a lot which makes me laugh harder. lol I'm laughing thinking about this.

Comment: I don't have any proof, but from my experience, I've met more than 10 people who laugh about their jokes (in a way that tries to force the other to laugh). Those people have probably a narcissism personality. Think of it: "You are trying to force people to laugh, you are trying to show off, you are not funny, but yet you want care about people thinking you are" is n't that narcissistic?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan those are narcissistic traits if that is what the person is thinking and trying to achieve.

Comment: Did u ever think we might laugh at our own jokes cos it's the first time we heard it ???? If someone keeps repeating it over and over to different people and still laughing every time then yes maybe but once definitely not...

Comment: I can't delete this, is has an answer.